# How to hide/show a QLabel and QTextEdit at the same time in my Qt application?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am working on a hide/show feature for my console in my Qt GUI application. The console consists of 2 widgets; QLabel and QTextEdit. Do I need to add the QLabel and QTextEdit to a QWidget in order to show/hide them, or is there a better way?

So basically I am looking for a container such as 'JPanel' in Java...

Comment: Show your source code please.

Comment: @duDE I am working in Qt designer, so I can post the code inside .ui, but I don't think it will be helpful, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to add the QLabel and QTextEdit to a QWidget in order to show/hide them, or is there a better way?

Multiple methods are possible here. You can, as you suggest, create a parent QWidget and add the QLabel and QTextEdit to a QWidget. Calling show and hide on the parent widget will affect its children.

Another method would be to have a slot function, which when an action is called, the slot calls show / hide on the 2 widgets.

Neither is right or wrong and depends upon the overall design of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think you need to use a [layout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-layouts.html) (horizontal / vertical):

> The simplest way to arrange objects on a form is to place them in a
>   horizontal or vertical layout. Horizontal layouts ensure that the
>   widgets within are aligned horizontally; vertical layouts ensure that
>   they are aligned vertically.
>
> Horizontal and vertical layouts can be combined and nested to any
>   depth. However, if you need more control over the placement of
>   objects, consider using the grid layout.

Comment: Whilst using layouts is a good idea, it doesn't answer the question posed, which asks how to show and hide multiple widgets.